How do I completely disable block editor?
I am trying to completely disable block editing and revert the entire site to the "classic editor version". I have already tried the disable gutenberg plug in, and the classic editor plug in, also, I have changed the editor version in the writing settings. With all of that done, I still have the black area that comes up on the left hand side with patterns templates , etc. when I try to customize the site.

What theme are you using. If you're using a block theme then you need the block editor.

It definitely sounds like you are using a block theme which requires Gutenberg. You will want to use a "Classic" WordPress theme as well.

Use ClassicPress: a fork of WordPress before Gutenberg was added to core, and is actively maintained and improved (latest version: June 2024), though not as frequently as WordPress (reduced community size).
